# trying to add loading wheel using angular when i make ajax call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement loading wheel directive when we make ajax call so during the response time i want to display loading wheen, With below code i do not see any error neither the loading wheel.

Is there any better way to implement loading wheel using angularJs ?

or

What is implemented wrong in below code ?

main.html

```
<loading></loading>

<ul style="list-style: none;">
    <li ng-repeat="message in event | limitTo:1000" ng-class="{lastItem: $last}"><span>{{message.value}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

loading.js

```
angular.module('App', [])
  .directive('loading', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        template: '<div class="loading"><img src="http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/videogallery/ajax-loader.gif" width="20" height="20" />LOADING...</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
              scope.$watch('loading', function (val) {
                  if (val)
                      $(element).show();
                  else
                      $(element).hide();
              });
        }
      }
  })
```

ctrl.js

```
$scope.searchServerFile = function() {
        console.log($scope.vm.search);
        if ($scope.vm.search === undefined || $scope.vm.search === null) {
            toastr.warning('A search keyword must only contain a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or space characters.');
        } else {
            $scope.loading = true;
            searchFactory.getServerSearch($scope.vm.search, searchEnv).then(function(response) {
                    $scope.modalInstance.rendered.then(function() {
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('displaySearchResults', {
                            messageObj: response.data

                        });
                        $scope.loading = false;
                    });
                }
        }
```

Comment: check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42701748/3543808)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of showing/hiding for each service call explicitly, you can use a directive to track the ajax request and show/hide the loading symbol at one place.

Below is the similar implementation

**Place the loading icon container in `index.html`**

```
<div class="loading-icon-container" loading>
    <div class="loading-icon">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ0tF.gif" width="28px" height="28px" alt="Loading..." />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Styling**

```
.loading-icon-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.loading-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**Implement `loading` directive**

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(function() {
            return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
        }, function(hasPending) {
            if (hasPending) {
                element[0].style.display = '';
            } else {
                element[0].style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    }
}
```

## Demo

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', []);

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('MyController', MyController)
  .directive('loading', loading)
  .factory('serviceFactory', serviceFactory);

MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'serviceFactory'];

function MyController($scope, serviceFactory) {

  $scope.serviceCall = function() {
    var reqObj = {
      url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?delay=3/photos',
      method: 'GET'
    }
    serviceFactory
      .serviceCall(reqObj)
      .then(function(data) {
        $scope.responseText = data.data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  };
}

loading.$inject = ['$http'];

function loading($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(function() {
        return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
      }, function(hasPending) {
        if (hasPending) {
          element[0].style.display = '';
        } else {
          element[0].style.display = 'none';
        }
      });
    }
  };
}

serviceFactory.$inject = ['$http'];

function serviceFactory($http) {
  var obj = {};
  obj.serviceCall = function(reqObj) {
    return $http(reqObj).then(function(success) {
      return success.data;
    });
  };
  return obj;

}
```

```css
.loading-icon-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.loading-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <button ng-click="serviceCall()">Servie call</button>
  <!-- loading icon -->
  <div class="loading-icon-container" loading>
    <div class="loading-icon"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ0tF.gif" width="28px" height="28px" alt="Loading..." />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--<div ng-bind="responseText|json">
  </div>-->

</div>
```

Comment: In my case i am calling factory in controller, is it possible to use that case with your logic

Comment: I just used `$http` in controller for the demo purpose. Ideally you should use factory to fetch data. **Yes. It will work whenever there is an AJAX call pending no matter whether you are calling in controller or using factory**

Comment: so in case of factory how i will use `loading()` function ?

Comment: I dont see in your code how you are using `loading` directive, You have mixed up everything in one file like controller,factory and directive. can you give me separate example of directive using with the factory. I am fairly new to directives,

Comment: @hussain I can understand you are new to [Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). I've given working example in file because stack snippets doesn't allow to create multiple files.

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation it worked but its not showing the text `Loading...`, Instead of external source can we use our oww image

Comment: Hello
its works for me but one small doubt so can i kept condition that if my http call take more then 1 sec then it will show else it shouid not show?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing an **interceptor** for HTTP requests.
Inside the interceptor you will fire events that you will be able to listen across the application.

Once it is happening you can use the events inside your main controller(or some directive) to show hide the loader.

```
MyApp.factory('Global-httpInterceptor', ['$q', '$rootScope', '$log', function ($q, $rootScope, $log) {

    var numLoadings = 0;

    return {
        request: function (config) {

            numLoadings++;
            // Show loader
            $rootScope.$broadcast("ajax:start", { $config: config });
            return config || $q.when(config);

        },
        response: function (response) {

            if ((--numLoadings) === 0) {
                // Hide loader
                $rootScope.$broadcast("ajax:finished", { $config: response });
            }
            $rootScope.$broadcast("ajax:success", { $response: response });

            return response || $q.when(response);

        },
        responseError: function (response) {

            if (!(--numLoadings)) {
                // Hide loader
                $rootScope.$broadcast("ajax:finished", { $response: response });
            }
            $rootScope.$broadcast("ajax:error", { $response: response });
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
}])
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('Global-httpInterceptor');
}]);
```

Example Use

```
angular.module('App', [])
  .directive('loading', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        template: '<div class="loading"><img src="http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/videogallery/ajax-loader.gif" width="20" height="20" />LOADING...</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            $rootScope.$on("ajax:start", function () {
                element.show();
            });
            $rootScope.$on("ajax:finished", function () {
                element.hide()
            });
        }
      }
  })
```

And at the view remains the same

```
<loading></loading>
```

Comment: can you give me an example how i will use this one from controller and view.

Comment: Yes, just added

Comment: Do we need to set boolean values in controller when we http request ?

Comment: No. Just add the "loader" directive at your loader html code and it will automatically shows/hide

Comment: On your case, you could just listen the events inside your "loading" directive, instead of creating the one in my example

Comment: so it will be like `<loading class="some spinner class" loader></loading>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137678/discussion-between-guilherme-ferreira-and-hussain).

Comment: dont have access to chat i just want to clarify  where i will add view and what it should in my case

Comment: oh OK. well, you dont need those classes, they are just examples. Gonna post your specific case on my post

Comment: I dont see my UI now do i need to download any module, No error in console, if i comment out directive i can see UI not sure what is happening

Comment: Did you replace the "MyApp" by your app module's name?

Comment: I had remove to `[]` from directive like `angular.module('loggingApp')
  .directive('loading', function () {})` it worked but it displayed loading wheel  continuously when i start application

Comment: then just add a element.hide() before the events inside your loading directive OR just hide on CSS (display:none) by default.

Comment: my css `.loading { border:1px solid #ddd; padding:20px; margin:40px 5px; width:80px; display: none;}` and html `<loading class="loading"></loading>`

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, what I would do instead would be to always have the loading wheel in the view, and just use `ng-if` to control whether it shows or not.

```
// view
<loading-wheel ng-if="vm.loading"/>
<content ng-if="!vm.loading"/>
```

And then, whenever you go to load, just set `vm.loading` (probably `this.loading` depending on context) to true, and when done, false. Then the loading wheel will show up when it's ready, and go away when it's done.

It's a lot cleaner and easier than manually showing and hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

Jeesk. Most of these answers seem like overkill, why not just include the image in your `controller` view and toggle it with an `ng-show` or `ng-if`?

( Please pardon my use of the API or whatever. Obviously the `$http` request should be abstracted into a service or something. I did this quickly and it's been a bit since I have worked with Angular 1)

```
angular.module("whatever")
  .controller("thing", function($scope, $http /* and whatever else*/) {


  $scope.isShowing = false;

  $scope.makeAJAXCall = function() {
    $scope.isShowing = true;

    $http.get("whatever.com")
      .success(function() {
      $scope.isShowing = false;
    });

  }
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="thing">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/150" alt="" ng-show="{{isShowing}}"/>
</div>
```