# AngularJs loader while http request are ongoing on page

Tags: angularjs, loader

I have developed an application I want to add loader in my system as I see  find  [BlockUI](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-block-ui) and make one demo but I have to kept it in every pages.

So is there any option there in angular that I can include it in one page and manage the flag from one place for all HTTP calls?

And it should remove only after all api calls are done.

Comment: share your code to let people help you

Comment: You can create your own blocker/loader. You can do that simply using CSS and some angular code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [loading icon while ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700582/trying-to-add-loading-wheel-using-angular-when-i-make-ajax-call)

Comment: @GangadharJannu thanks it helps me

Comment: @GangadharJannu Hello
its works for me but one small doubt so can i kept condition that if my http call take more then 1 sec then it will show else it shouid not show?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is what you are wanting but based on the title - if someone is looking for a loader that is ridiculously easy to implement I've used [loading bar](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/)

just include it in your app and it works automatically using interceptors.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angular-loading-bar'])
```

Doesn't block the UI but does provide the loader. (Not sure from question which is the requirement?)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a factory for `$http` calls and in that factory add listeners for the ajax load and end events. In that listeners add your loader show and hide events. Here is a sample code. Here I have used a google map service to get location and [angular broadcast](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/angularjs/understanding-emit-broadcast-and-on-in-angularjs) events to show and hide the loader.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

        app.config(function ($httpProvider) {

        });

        app.factory('httpPreConfig', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
            $http.defaults.transformRequest.push(function () {
                console.log('Started');
                //Show your loader here
                $rootScope.$broadcast('AjaxProgress');
            });
            $http.defaults.transformResponse.push(function () {
                console.log('Stopped');
                //Hide your loader here
                $rootScope.$broadcast('AjaxFinished');
            })
            return $http;
        }]);

        app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, httpPreConfig) {
            $scope.showLoader = false;
            $scope.sendGet = function () {
                httpPreConfig.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=america');
            };
            
            $rootScope.$on('AjaxProgress', function(){
                $scope.showLoader = true;
            });
            
            $rootScope.$on('AjaxFinished', function(){
                $scope.showLoader = false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-if="showLoader">Loader</div>
    <button ng-click="sendGet()">Send Get</button>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: ya i can use but its a last priority for this i have to emit message in every API calll

Comment: I created one directive and addded some css and its works for me