# AngularJS multiple loader on same page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I have implemented single loader of the application. as i have added this  [Working Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700582/trying-to-add-loading-wheel-using-angular-when-i-make-ajax-call)  and kept code in my index file so it works for me.

But I want multiple loaders on same page

so how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

presently i'm using this [cgbusy](https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy).. based on api call promise it will show loading until data loaded. you can use multiple loading also.